# Cannot retrieve a Float array from a hashtable

Tags: java, arrays, hashtable

I am limited to using legacy collections in Java.
I created a Hashtable

```
private Hashtable dataStock = new Hashtable();
```

and one of the entries of this hashtable is a Float array

```
dataStock.put("someArray", new Float[24]);
```

When I want to retrieve this entry from the hashtable like this:

```
Float[] anotherArray = (Float[]) dataStock.get("someArray");
```

I get the following cast exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException
at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(<unknown source file>:130)
at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(<unknown source file>:51)
at java.lang.Exception.<init>(<unknown source file>:13)
at java.lang.RuntimeException.<init>(<unknown source file>:18)
at java.lang.ClassCastException.<init>(<unknown source file>:17)
at fr.ecosense.business.FlashMemory.restoreStockData(FlashMemory.java:297)
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is storing arrays in a Hashtable different to storing other objects? I was looking for an explication but there is little information on storing arrays in hashtables.

EDIT: I am using Java ME. Maybe this can cause some unexpected behaviour..

Comment: You are doing everything correctly. The exception you received is produced due to some other causes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for demonstration. This piece of code:

```
    Hashtable dataStock = new Hashtable();
    dataStock.put("someArray", new Float[24]);
    Float[] anotherArray = (Float[]) dataStock.get("someArray");
```

works well. That means, that somewhere in your code you put into your `dataStock` some other value with key `someArray` which type differs from `Float[]`.

Comment: Indeed, somewhere I put another array with the same key which is of type float[], and not Float[]. Thanks!